# How should I store product information to display in Android listbox-based UI?

Tags: android, database-design

Hello there,

I am new to Android development.

I am developing an application in which I want to display information about a product. The user will select the product from a listbox and get the information on the following screen.

My question pertains to the design of the information storage: should I store information of all products in the database or is it better to use an  external storage system like files as information related to a product will be quite big.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise using external storage as a database will be more efficient in storing and retrieving information related to your product. This is why they are called "relational" databases.

You did not give information about the information to be displayed, but it seems logical to assume you can divide into logical parts that may be stored in tables. Flat-files would be much more inefficient.

I advise you to use SQLite on Android, with a table Products (id, description, ...) that is related to your tables of information.

I hope this helps.